# ¿Cómo grabar en Base de Datos mediante onclick

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero grabar un dato en una base de datos MySql cuando se pulse un boton.

Estoy intentandolo, sin conseguirlo, con el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
//Declaración de funciones
function Grabar_Apartado($apartado,$nombre_al) 
    {
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicas") or
        die("Problemas con la conexión");
    mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos
            set siguiente_apartado='$apartado' where nombre_alumno='$nombre_al'") or
            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
//Fin de declaración de funciones
$apart= '3t' ;
$nomb_al='R';

?>

<Input id="Button2" type="button" value="Pulse para grabar" 
     onclick ="Grabar_Apartado(<?echo "$apart"; ?>,<? echo "$nomb_al";?> )"; />
```

- 

He hecho algunos avances pero sin llegar a conseguir que funcione lo que quiero.

Este codigo funciona OK (pero todavía no sirve) (javascript llama a una funcion php sin parametros. Los valores están en la propia función php):

```
//Declaración de funciones
function Grabar_Apartado($apartado,$nombre_al) 
    {
        $apartado='4t';
        $nombre_al='R';
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicas") or
        die("Problemas con la conexión");
    mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos
            set siguiente_apartado='$apartado' where nombre_alumno='$nombre_al'") or
            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
//Fin de declaración de funciones
  ?>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Grabar Datos" id="boton1" onclick = "funcion();">
<script>
    function funcion(){
        document.write(<?php echo Grabar_Apartado(); ?>);
  }

</script>
```

- 

Este otro codigo, el siguiente peldaño avanzado, también funciona (javascript llama a una funcion php con parametros, que son unas constantes):

```
//Declaración de funciones
function Grabar_Apartado($apartado,$nombre_al) 
    {
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicas") or
        die("Problemas con la conexión");
    mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos
            set siguiente_apartado='$apartado' where nombre_alumno='$nombre_al'") or
            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
//Fin de declaración de funciones
  ?>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Grabar Datos" id="boton1" onclick = "funcion();">
<script>
    function funcion(){
        document.write(<?php echo Grabar_Apartado('2t','R'); ?>);
  }
</script>
```

- 

Pero el siguiente código, que solucionaria mi problema, no funciona, a pesar de probar diversas variaciones (javascript llama a una funcion php con parametros, que son unas variables):

```
//Declaración de funciones
function Grabar_Apartado($apartado,$nombre_al) 
    {
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","practicas") or
        die("Problemas con la conexión");
    mysqli_query($conexion, "update alumnos
            set siguiente_apartado='$apartado' where nombre_alumno='$nombre_al'") or
            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
//Fin de declaración de funciones
  ?>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Grabar Datos" id="boton1" onclick = "funcion();">
<script>
    var apart='4t';
    var nom_al='R';
    function funcion(){
        document.write(<?php echo Grabar_Apartado("$apart","$nom_al"); ?>);
  }
</script>
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con el último avance?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estas mezclando codigo de js con php, tu error radica (posiblemente) en el entendimiento de cada lenguaje... php se ejecuta del lado del servidor, mientras que js se ejecuta del lado del cliente, por esta razon el codigo de js no puede "llamar" una funcion en php.

En tu codigo estas insertando el resultado de una funcion de php en el "output" (que incluye codigo de js), cuando cambias los valores por variables deja de funcionar en el servidor porque el codigo de php NO tiene acceso a las variables (que declaras en js) y porque en el codigo de js NO se usa $ para las variables.

Aparentemente "funciona" y graba en la db, pero (tal vez) no te has dado cuenta que no necesitas presionar el boton para que lo grabe, ya que graba en la db antes de mostrar la pagina.

Por lo anterior y debido a que me imagino que lo que quieres es que cuando opriman el boton (en el cliente) se ejecute una funcion en tu servidor que grabe la informacion en una db, lo que tendras que hacer es; primero.- entender como se usa ajax en js para "mandar" informcion al servidor, segundo.- separar tu "output" que genera la pagina de la funcion de grabacion en a db, tercero.- desde la funcion en js, tienes que llamar a tu script en el servidor y, cuarto.- tu script de php tiene que recibir la informacion de js y grabar

aqui tienes algunos links que puedes leer:

[how-to-make-an-ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

[simple-php-ajax-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603986/simple-php-ajax-request)

modifica tu codigo, añade o modifica tu pregunta con el nuevo codigo (si aun no lo logras) sera un gusto ayudarte.